# Firebase Phone Auth: Does white listing real numbers cause an sms to be sent?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase allows us to test phone numbers without using real phone numbers (by white listing the numbers from the console).

But firebase states this in the docs:

> Make sure you use fictional numbers that do not already exist. Firebase Authentication does not allow you to whitelist existing phone numbers used by real users. One option is to use 555 prefixed numbers as US test phone numbers, for example: +1 650-555-3434.

**Question:**

1) If I added real phone number in the white list, does it mean that it might be possible to send an sms to this device?

2) I don't know how I can provide a fake number in my country, so following what firebase recommends:

They state that we use 555 prefixed numbers, now I don't know what this means. I think that in this number (+1 650-555-3434):

+1 : country code for US.

650 : Area code.

555 : A number that should be there to make the number fake.

3434 : Any random number that I can provide.

Is this the meaning of a fake number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you provide a real phone number for testing, no SMS will be sent (the code you configure would need to be provided to complete sign in). The point of the feature to simplify phone authentication development.
With test phone numbers:

1. No SMS is sent, so no charges incurred (you won't use up your quota).
2. The same phone number can be used for testing without getting throttled.
3. You can test in a simulator, without using silent push notifications, reCAPTCHA, etc.

US 555 area codes are not real phone numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number).

I'm not sure if each country has equivalent fictional numbers. It is OK to use real phone numbers. The important thing is to not use phone numbers that belong to real users. You can probably whitelist your own phone number or your development team's phone numbers, etc which you plan to use for development.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.